# setInterval not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use setInterval in Javascript to redraw the canvas periodically. However, when I call the setInterval function, the function I pass to it only runs once. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

function makeBoard()
{
    this.board=[["O", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", "X", " "]];
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ticTacToeBoard=new makeBoard();

var drawCanvas = new Function("printBoard", "");

drawCanvas = function(printBoard)
{
    alert("Calling draw function.");
    // drawing code
}

setInterval(drawCanvas(ticTacToeBoard), 10);
</script>
```

I've tested this on Firefox 54.0.1 and on Google Chrome Version 59.0. Why is this not working and how can I get my code to redraw the canvas periodically?

Comment: You're passing the returned result of calling `drawCanvas(ticTacToeBoard)` to `setInterval()`

Comment: `setInterval(() => drawCanvas(ticTacToeBoard), 10);`

Comment: Your code is basically `setInterval(undefined, 10);`

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that setInterval worked that way. It's running fine now, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass a function definition to the setInterval method, not the result of a function call.

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Do something
}, 1000);
```

For your case,

```
setInterval(function() {
  drawCanvas(ticTacToeBoard);
}, 10);
```